# progressive or simple

Tags: continuous

Is it possible to write this answer instead the one given in that test

My mother fell ill last week. I am making all the meals instead of her. She still does not feel well so she is seeing a doctor tomorrow . I hope she will get better soon.

Can it be possible to change     **does not feel** by **is not feeling well** and **she will get** by **will be getting**

because both actions are not realised at moment of speaking they are still in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original statement:

> My mother fell ill last week. I am making all the meals instead of
>   her. She still **does not feel well** so she is seeing a doctor tomorrow.
>   I hope **she will get** better soon.

Your proposed statement:

> My mother fell ill last week. I am making all the meals instead of
>   her. She still **is not feeling well** so she is seeing a doctor tomorrow.
>   I hope **she will be getting** better soon.

About your first change, it is evident that you should also swap the "still" and "is," i.e "**She is still not feeling well, so..."** (That comma will help phrase things better, in my opinion.)

I believe that this replacement is perfectly acceptable, both in terms of grammar and how it would sound to a Native Speaker.

Your second change does seem to be grammatically correct (at least according to Grammarly) but does feel a bit too awkward. I believe it stems from the fact that it is longer than it has to be, and strays away from the typical "get better/well" phrase which is used ("getting" is not used as often, in this context.)

In fact, a valid change to the last sentence could be **"I hope she *gets* better soon."**

Comment: i don't undestand what you mean by   I believe it stems from the fact that it is longer than it has to be, and strays away from the typical "get better/well" phrase which is used ("getting" is not used as often, in this context.)  could you please explain me will accept as soon as you have explained me

Comment: Sorry, I made that sentence too complicated.

 I was trying to say that most people only say "get well." They do not say "getting well" as often.